# No module named scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I run the following command:

`python3 -m scrapy crawl quote -o quote.json`

It shows:

`/home/computernerd/Desktop/Scrapy/scrapy.tasting/bin/python3: No module named scrapy`

The reason why I am using `python3 -m` is because when I trying using `scrapy crawl quote -o quote.json` I get an error - `scrapy command not found`

Comment: `scrapy` is a third-party module -- it does not come built in to Python.  You have to install it yourself.  Did you install it?

Comment: Does this return anything? `python3 -m pip freeze | grep scrapy`

Answer (score 0):

You have a local directory named "scrapy" that python finds instead of the module.

Answer (score 0):

See if Scrapy is installed. If not installed then install it through

```
pip install Scrapy
```

and try again.